# tcp сеть в omnet++

Tags: c++, tcp

Я пытаюсь построить простую tcp сеть в omnet++.[image: tcp-сеть]

[image: Структура]

код WindowsSize.ned:

```
package simulations;

import inet.networklayer.configurator.ipv4.Ipv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.networklayer.ipv4.IIpv4;
import inet.node.inet.StandardHost;
import ned.DatarateChannel;

network ClientServer
{
    @display("bgb=500,339");
    submodules:
        client: StandardHost {
            @display("p=113,158");
        }
        server: StandardHost {
            @display("p=320,158;i=device/server");
        }
        configurator: Ipv4NetworkConfigurator {
            @display("p=222,46");
        }
    connections:
        client.pppg++ <--> DatarateChannel {  delay = 0.1us; datarate = 10Mbps; } <--> server.pppg++;
}
```

код WindowsSize.ini:

```
[General]
description = "default_TCP <---> default_TCP" 
network = ClientServer
sim-time-limit = 100s
total-stack = 7MiB
record-eventlog = true 
**.server.numPcapRecorders = 1
**.server.pcapRecorder[0].pcapFile = "server.pcap" 
**.client.numPcapRecorders = 1
**.client.pcapRecorder[0].pcapFile = "client.pcap"

**.numTcpApps = 1
**.client*.tcpApp[*].typename = "TCPSessionApp" 
**.client*.tcpApp[0].active = true 
**.client*.tcpApp[0].localPort = -1 
**.client*.tcpApp[0].connectAddress = "server" 
**.client*.tcpApp[0].connectPort = 1000 
**.client*.tcpApp[0].tOpen = 0.2s 
**.client*.tcpApp[0].tSend = 0.4s 
**.client*.tcpApp[0].sendBytes = 5000000B 
**.client*.tcpApp[0].sendScript = "" 
**.client*.tcpApp[0].tClose = 25s

**.server*.tcpApp[*].typename = "TCPEchoApp" 
**.server*.tcpApp[0].localPort = 1000 
**.server*.tcpApp[0].echoFactor = 0 
**.server*.tcpApp[0].echoDelay = 0

**.ppp[*].queueType = "DropTailQueue" 

**.ppp[*].queue.frameCapacity = 10 

*.configurator.config=xml("<config><interface hosts='*' address='192.168.1.x' netmask='255.255.255.0'/></config>")
```

В итоге при симуляции возникает ошибка:
[image: Возникающая ошибка]

как это исправить?